UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o209.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Schema cannot be updated: data type has been changed, new data type:
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o209.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Schema cannot be updated: data type has been changed, new data type: [payment_logs@gateway_discount] optional int32 payment_logs@gateway_discount (DECIMAL(4,2)) does not match old data type: [payment_logs@gateway_discount] optional int32 payment_logs@gateway_discount (DECIMAL(3,2))
I am writing the dynamic frame into Amazon S3 by using sink object because I require a catalog for the dynamic frame.
Things done-> casted the columns causing the issues still not worked. used glueparquetwriter=true also did format from glueparquet to parquet. Not resolved.
